# ngModel property not working in my sub html component

Tags: html, angular

I guys, I am new in angular. I created an angular app and in it I have 3 other generated components to test angular navigation. Here is what I need help with, in the "index.html" when I use "[(ngModel)]" in the an input element, it flags no error but if I try to use **"[(ngModel)]"** in any of the 3 created components html file, it gives my error. I have imported "FormsModule" in the app.module.ts.

Please I do I make the ngModel property available in my sub html components?

It will be appreciated if you answer with examples.

Cheers

Comment: Try posting your code, so we can help you find what's missing

Comment: Please attach your code

Comment: What is the error message? That will usually give a good clue into the issue. A copy of the code used would also greatly increase the ability for others to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `import FormsModule`

example:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: I'm having issues with [mfData], any idea on how to fix it? The error say: isn't a known property of 'table'.

Answer (score 0):

Add `FormsModule` in your `AppModule`. Because `template-driven forms` are in their own module, you need to add the `FormsModule` to the array of imports for the application module before you can use forms. for more information read this https://angular.io/guide/forms

```
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: I'm having issues with [mfData], any idea on how to fix it? The error say: isn't a known property of 'table'.